# PHP parse json array with cookies and set all cookies from it

Tags: php, mysql, json, cookies, setcookie

I need save all cookies from domain in mysql table and then get it from mysql and then set for user.

Here's example:

```
$cookies = json_encode($_COOKIE);
//save $cookies to mysql 
//...get it from mysql in $mysqlCookies
```

And now I need `setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, ...)` 
How can I parse json `$mysqlCookies` in 2 variables, like `$cookie_name` and `$cookie_value`, which should save name and value from `$mysqlCookies`?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? What is your issue? That the cookies aren't setting?

Comment: I don't know HOW to split `$mysqlCookies` in 2 variables which should contains cookie NAME and value.

Comment: What does `$mysqlCookies` look like?

Comment: @Darren {"cookiename1":"123","cookiename2":"123"} and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `json_decode()`.

```
$thecookies = json_decode($mysqlCookies);

foreach($thecookies as $name => $value) {
    setcookie($name, $value, time()+3600); // expires 1 hour..
}
```

The above will set your cookies properly as you require.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)/[unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) insted of [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)/[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) since the cookies are just transported between PHP and the database.

### Saving to database

```
$cookies = serialize($_COOKIE);
// Write the $cookies string to a column in the database
```

### Reading from database

```
$cookies = unserialize($cookieColumnFromDatabase)

foreach ($cookies as $cookieName => $cookieValue) {
    setcookie($cookieName, $cookieValue);
}
```